# Criar uma lista de palavras para ser lida por um plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Eu preciso criar um grupo de palavras, a ser definido em um textarea, no painel admin do Wordpress, em uma página de configuração do meu plugin.

Eu tenho os seguinte código:

```
add_filter('pre_comment_content', 'palavras_indesejadas'); 
    function palavras_indesejadas($content { 
        //$palavras = get_comment_text();
        $palavras = array('teste', 'testando');

        foreach($palavras as $palavra) { 
            $content = str_replace($palavra, "******", $content); 
        } 
            return $content; 
        }
```

Ele vai identificar neste array quais as palavras eu definir, mas eu não sei como criar uma tabela ou campo no banco de dados que eu possa salvar estas palavras e depois o plugin possa pesquisar por elas no banco.

Quanto a página de configuração, eu sei mais ou menos como cria, eu só estou em dúvida mesmo de como salvar essa informação no banco e trazer pra dentro do meu array.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, na tentativa e erro, mas não tenho certeza se essa é a melhor prática.

Primeiro, eu tive que adaptar o trecho de busca das palavras:

```
$palavras = array( 
    explode( ',', get_option('palavras') ) 
);
```

E neste trecho registro a opção

```
function palavras_indesejadas_config() {
   add_option('palavras', 'exemplos, de, palavras');
   register_setting('options', 'palavras', 'callback');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'palavras_indesejadas_config' );
```

E então eu chamo `settings_fields( 'options' );` dentro da página do meu plugin.

```
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
      <?php settings_fields( 'options' ); ?>
        <input type="text" id="palavras" name="palavras" 
        placeholder="<?php echo get_option('palavras'); ?>" />
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
```